# NodeJS / Socket.IO / Communication between server & client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, emit

Good Morning,
I have a little problem. About the past week I have been working with NodeJS and currently writing a bot, which accepts incomming Steam Trade Offer.
For this I use some steam-packages and socket.io. I have a function to check the items (souvenir, float, value, etc) and it is working correctly. After the server checked the whole offer, it is sending a socket to all connected clients.

```
// node-bot.js
socket.broadcast.emit('receiveOffer',{
    value: totaldeposit,
    offerid: offer.id,
    items: offer.itemsToGive,
    userid: offer.partner.getSteamID64()
});
```

Usually the user is receiving this socket - this is not the problem. After receiving the socket, i want to decline it directly (for debugging)

```
// app.js
socket.on('receiveOffer', function(data) {
    console.log("Offer received: " + data);
    socket.emit('declineOffer', {offerid:data.offerid});
});
```

My console is logging `Offer received: [Object object]`.
But my server is not receiving this emitted socket `declineOffer`. My function is looking like this:

```
socket.on('declineOffer', function(offer) {
    console.log("declineOffer emitted ");
});
```

But the server is not printing my string `declineOffer emitted`. What am i doing wrong? Is there something i should do differently?

Comment: can you try 'socket.broadcast.emit('declineOffer', {offerid:data.offerid});'
and check that event triggered or not?

Comment: Can you add hot you initialize `socket` on the server?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. When I get the event on the client, I receive declineOffer on the server. Please post complete sample.